# Why can't I change my Nikon D3200 aperture in Live View?

Tags: nikon, aperture, live-view

I removed the lens to show to the shutter release. While putting the lens back on I didn't place it correctly on the first attempt. Also, when I removed the lens, the camera was on and possibly in live view.

Now, the aperture doesn't change while in Live View mode. (Yes, I'm holding down the -/+ button. Also while it is on manual.) I can only change the aperture while in viewfinder mode.

Did I mess something up? Or is it in the settings somewhere?

Comment: See also: [Is it normal that manual exposure does not work on the Nikon D7000 in Live-View?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/12500)

Comment: See also: [Why is my Nikon D3200 display not changing in manual mode?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/39111)

Answer (score 5):

We can't change f-stops in nikon d3200 in live view mode because when the mirror is lifted up the aperture-setting lever stops working. It works fine in viewfinder mode since the mirror is down.

Just to clarify your doubt please switch to different lens and try changing f-stops in live view.

Comment: Thanks for your response rafal.

I was able to change the f-stop in live view before. That is why in concern.

Also, when I removed the lens, the camera was on and possibly in live view.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

In movie settings, you have to manual movie setting off in order to be able to change the aperture in live view.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be a bug in the software. Seems stupid that one has to do this!

Comment: Manual movie setting off renders a change in aperture, shutter speed and ISO setting of software irrelevant, I believe it is a shortcut to having changes through lens aperture rings.